# Ajax no reconoce el dataType: "json"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto con PHP, MySQL y jQuery. Al momento de utilizar `$.ajax()` y querer añadirle `dataType: "json"`, aparentemente Ajax no lo esta recibiendo de la manera correcta, ya que no llega a la funcion success, si no, que se pasa a la funcion error.

Mi codigo de ajax es el siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ajax/api.php?accion=obtener-lista-empresas",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success:function(response){
            alert(response);
            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                $('#slc-empresa-devolucion').append('<option value="'+response[i].RTN+'">'+response[i].nombreEmpresa+'</option>');
            }
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Mi codigo de la API es el siguiente

```
include ("../class/conexion.php");
include ("../class/class-empresas.php");

$conexion = new Conexion();

switch ($_GET["accion"]){

        case "obtener-lista-empresas":
            $empr = new empresas(null,null,null,null);
            echo $empr->obtenerListaEmpresas($conexion);
        break;
}
```

Y mi codigo de la class-empresas.php es el siguiente:

```
<?php

    class empresas{

        private $idEmpresa;
        private $nombreEmpresa;
        private $RTN;
        private $direccionPrincipal;

        public function __construct($idEmpresa,
                    $nombreEmpresa,
                    $RTN,
                    $direccionPrincipal){
            $this->idEmpresa = $idEmpresa;
            $this->nombreEmpresa = $nombreEmpresa;
            $this->RTN = $RTN;
            $this->direccionPrincipal = $direccionPrincipal;
        }
        public function getIdEmpresa(){
            return $this->idEmpresa;
        }
        public function setIdEmpresa($idEmpresa){
            $this->idEmpresa = $idEmpresa;
        }
        public function getNombreEmpresa(){
            return $this->nombreEmpresa;
        }
        public function setNombreEmpresa($nombreEmpresa){
            $this->nombreEmpresa = $nombreEmpresa;
        }
        public function getRTN(){
            return $this->RTN;
        }
        public function setRTN($RTN){
            $this->RTN = $RTN;
        }
        public function getDireccionPrincipal(){
            return $this->direccionPrincipal;
        }
        public function setDireccionPrincipal($direccionPrincipal){
            $this->direccionPrincipal = $direccionPrincipal;
        }
        public function __toString(){
            return "IdEmpresa: " . $this->idEmpresa .
                " NombreEmpresa: " . $this->nombreEmpresa .
                " RTN: " . $this->RTN .
                " DireccionPrincipal: " . $this->direccionPrincipal;
        }

        public function obtenerListaEmpresas($conexion){

            $sql = "SELECT idEmpresa,
            nombreEmpresa,
            RTN,
            direccionPrincipal
            FROM empresa";

            $resultado = $conexion->ejecutarConsulta($sql);
            $listaEmpresas = array();
            while($fila = $conexion->obtenerFila($resultado)){
                $listaEmpresas[] = $fila;
            }

            return json_encode($listaEmpresas);

        }


    }
?>
```

Lo interesante es que, en la funcion error, me aparece toda la informacion que se esta mandando a llamar de la base de datos en forma de JSON, por lo tanto no se cual es el problema.

Y si en el ajax busco eliminar el dataType, si llega a la funcion success, pero logicamente, la informacion no se utiliza de la manera correcta, por lo tanto, me aparecen infinitos `<option value="undefined">undefined</option>`

Comment: En vez de un alert usa un console.log(response) para poder ver que te devuelve. Por lo común te trae un arreglo y puedes tener una idea mas clara de que podría ser.

Comment: Te recomendaria que antes de pasar el array por el for, verifiques que si llegue la data y que sea un array, por que si no llega nada o llega mal la data, el for va a explotar

Comment: Realice la idea de Juan Carlos y en vez del alert puse el console.log, y me aparece lo siguiente:

conectado con mysql[{"idEmpresa":"1","nombreEmpresa":"Walmart","RTN":"08019999176681","direccionPrincipal":"Blv. Centroamerica, Edificio IPM"},{"idEmpresa":"2","nombreEmpresa":"La Colonia","RTN":"08019995224132","direccionPrincipal":"Colonia Alameda"}]

Esta informacion es la que se encuentra en la base de datos y se ha llamado correctamente

Comment: Probablemente estás teniendo un error del tipo JSON parse porque estás fastidiando el JSON en el servidor con esto **`conectado con mysql`**. Cuando trabajas con respuestas de tipo JSON tienes que hilar fino en el servidor, controlando todas las salidas por pantalla. **En todo el flujo no puede salir por pantalla otra cosa que tu JSON**. Es posible que en la conexión por ejemplo hayas puesto un  `echo` con ese mensaje, debes quitarlo y debes quitar cualquier otra salida en el flujo del código que no sea el JSON. Con eso debería resolverse el problema.

Comment: Justamente eso utilice para solucionar el error A. Cedano, elimine el "conectado con mysql" y eso hizo que pudiera trabajar tranquilamente con la informacion del JSON

Answer (score 0):

Ya que usas jQuery, puedes usar funciones cortas sin emplear dataType

```
$.get("ajax/api.php?accion=obtener-lista-empresas", (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $('#slc-empresa-devolucion').append('<option value="'+response[i].RTN+'">'+response[i].nombreEmpresa+'</option>');
    }
}, (fail) => {
    console.log(fail);
});
```

Comment: Intente realizar esta solución, y no funciono lastimosamente